# My http-parser.c callbacks are undeclared

Tags: c

I am working on a server. I have included the http-parser.h header file and used their code for how to use it. However, when I compile I get the following errors:

```
'my_url_callback' undeclared
'my_header_field_callback' undeclared
'my_socket' undeclared
```

I assumed that these were defined in the header file. Apparently, I was mistaken. How should I declare these?

Comment: I'm sorry, but where is your code?

Comment: I am afraid my code is so messy it would be of little use. I supposes I should add it anyway.

Comment: The expression you're looking for is: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You suppose correctly; you need to show how the functions are declared in a (minimal) version of your header.  You also need to verify that the header is included where the functions are used (and where they're defined!).  You should be able to copy'n'paste some way or another.  If necessary, save the file in `emacs`, then `cat` the file in a terminal command window, and use the terminal's copy mechanism (shift-control-c perhaps) to copy what you've got highlighted so you can paste it into your browser.